# Locking bad tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, burninate-system

There is a tag which has following excerpt:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It is ambiguous and not helpful.

There are 1369 questions tagged with it. This warning in excerpt appeared over one year ago. Since then this tag gained over 300 new questions. I do not mention the name of this tag to not distract the discussion.

Lets assume that this tag is wrong and should be burninated. Lets assume that there was thorough 'burninate discussion' on meta and verdict was very strong toward burnination.

But the problem is that this tag had so many questions. And that there were not enough voluntiers to do the burnination. In such situations there is nothing more we can do against such tag.

This tag still exists and is still growing not because it is a good tag but because it is too big to fall.

My proposition of solution to this problem is:

There should be possible to lock a tag. Lock would be activated if enough users voted for it. There would be also possible to vote against the lock. So tag defenders would have a chance to gather up and unlock the tag.

Active lock would have following consequences on question:

- it is not possible to tag new question with locked tag
- it is not possible to add such tag to existing question
- (optionally) while doing edit user will be forced to remove such tag

And consequences for burnination process:

- bad tag will not grow
- tag burninators would span this process for a long period of time and would see the progress.
- askers are often adding such tag in good faith. If tag was locked they would be stopped.
- big number of questions tagged with such tag will no longer be an excuse against burnination

**What do you think about my proposal?**

Comment: My proposed solution was to [utilize the tag-synonym system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232279).

Comment: Isn't this pretty much what tag blacklisting is intended for?

Comment: [(less complicated) MSE dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151920/179419).

Comment: @animuson against what you would synonymize something like [problem]? or [tables] as said in James answer? Synonymization has some uses, but it fairs poorly in the "crap tag prevention" (in fact, most tags that should be synonyms are fine, just that there's another tag that means roughly the same)

Comment: @Braiam My suggestion over there is to synonymize them all into a single "blacklisted" tag. Not into other tags.

Comment: @animuson Why not just use the new blacklist system that is in place?

Comment: @Seth There is no new blacklist system. They've merely added the ability to attach messages to blacklisted user input. It's still the same list that they try to keep at a minimal size (and moderators have no ability to edit).

Comment: @animuson Huh, you're right. That wasn't what I was told before though.. odd.

Comment: Forcing people to remove the tag is not ideal.  It would be better if the system removed the tag when the edit is made (so the verboten tag is not displayed, and a removal notice might be added to the edit description).  It might notify the editor that it has happened.  If for some reason the verboten tag is the only tag, then the editor might be required to add a non-verboten tag, or the tag could be left and a note posted asking for a change (but not penalizing the editor if they cannot find a new tag to use in its place).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's not a good solution that system removes verboten tag from editted post. Often there will be situation that verboten tag should be replaced by one of more specific tag. So maybe just warn editer that he should do something with this tag but allow him to ignore this warning and submit edit anyway.

Comment: @rtruszk: that works too.  The crucial point is that the editor should not submit the edit and get it rejected; those are the most annoying messages.  The one that really gets my goat is the forbidden words in the question title when I've not added the forbidden word to the title.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You think 1600 questions is bad?
I found a tag the other day [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) which has 21k questions!
The "table" tag is getting [4-5 new questions each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table?sort=newest&pageSize=50), as people are ignoring the "DO NOT USE".

So, yes, perhaps your feature would be useful.
At least it'll stop these tags from gaining more questions, so users can do some burninating tasks on it now and then and *eventually* clear it up.

---

Obviously the tag would require at least 1 synonym before being able to vote to lock it.
And I would suggest really good criteria on who can vote and how many needed.
As this is likely an infrequent occurrence, and also locking down a popular and legitimate tag would be quite bad.

---

That said, is there much need for this?
As burninate usually sorts the issue out, how many tags are actually in this *state* - whereby they need to be stopped from being used before burnination can begin without it being an endless task?

Comment: Would it help if there were language specific tags. In the case of `table`, it is a function in R that might generate a request as well as being a concept in SQL. 441 of the current `[table]` tags are also listed at `[r]` tags.

Comment: @BondedDust I hear a [retag-request]?

Comment: *That said, is there much need for this?* Yes I think so. There is a [high confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btag%5D+%22do+not+use%22) about the do-not-use tags and lot of issues would get resolved by having a built-in *tag lock* instead of a *do-not-use disclaimer*