# Why do some tag descriptions contain DO NOT USE, but still get new questions. Can we not "lock" certain tags

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, tags

While writing questions a few times I have come across tags that contain a description that starts with

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG!

[image]

An example of this is the [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) tag

So my first question is; if we are not supposed to use this tag, what is it doing here?

And secondly, even when the tag contains the message `DO NOT USE THIS TAG!` people still use it, shown below [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) has 47 new questions this month.
[image]

So from this we can see that this method isn't very effective in stopping people using the tag. which leads onto my second question. Is there any way which the tag can still "exist" for old questions but be "locked" (probably by a moderator) so that new questions cannot use the tag?

**PS**

If there currently isn't a mechanism for locking tags, should/could this be a feature that gets implemented?

Comment: Just because it doesn't prevent *everyone* from using the tag doesn't mean that it doesn't at least limit the number of people who use it.

Comment: @Servy Agreed. But IMO this tag should have 0 new questions as the tag correctly states `This tag is hopelessly broad`

Comment: Why didnt they just kill it and remove it alltogether? Its so broad no question loses value by losing it.

Comment: It is there so SO users can learn not to use the tag.  Reactivating thousands of crappy questions just to get rid of a tag that nobody cares about is not an alternative.  SE employees can black-list a tag but they are never eager to do so.

Comment: I found my answer with a duplicate question at: [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280215/locking-bad-tags?rq=1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280215/locking-bad-tags?rq=1)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307068/4639281

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to prevent a tag from being added to new questions while it is still tagged to some number of existing questions.