# "DO NOT USE" tags: why don't we remove them?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, user-interface

I noticed, [as some people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308810/why-do-some-tag-descriptions-contain-do-not-use-but-still-get-new-questions-ca) here [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271356/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-do-not-use-tags), that some tags are displaying "**DO NOT USE**" in their description. Why does it ever exists such tags that are literally here to be **not used** ?

Why can we not have a sort of "trial" for new tags ? I know you can implement your own tags, but this is just noise to the mass of tags that are actually useful. We could have some display, like:

> This tag is not yet valid: it needs to gather at least X followers within the next Y days / weeks / months, or it will be removed.

at the creation of a tag. This would bring new interesting tags where a **decent** number of people subscribed, while eliminating all superficial ones. On top of that, moderators could still apply some control over subjectives ones ?

... And some more achievements to people who succeed in implementing nice tags. Wait, just scratch that. The question is above.

Comment: Because they will be re-created and when blacklisted, they whine on meta that we are discriminating against certain tags ... it is not perfect, still better then nothing ...

Comment: If the tag is destroyed then the DO NOT USE message is deleted as well.  So somebody will recreate it and then somebody will get it deleted again and on and on it goes in endless cycles.  Only SE employees can black-list a tag, a super-power they very rarely apply.

Comment: @xenteros: Questions with no tags happens all the time. They simply get the special [tag:untagged] tag.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most of the **DO NOT USE** tags have a lot of questions in them. Those tags used to be valid in the past; we didn't have a quality system (a.k.a. [burninate requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request)) back then. If we tried to remove those tags now, we'd get too many worthless old questions bumped to the front page.

A trial is not a bad idea, but the problem is that some libraries/frameworks/programming languages are very unpopular and would *never* get the required amount of followers / questions, if you were to put a meaningful threshold for JavaScript, Java, or C#-related tags. I think this continues to be a process with a lot of manual work involved for the community.

Comment: I think SE should implement a new field in the tag system for tags being disallowed: they would be not pickable but still listable

Comment: @LuisMasuelli A soft blacklist would be awesome.

Comment: Or a way to remove a tag without bumping the question, or indeed without having to remove it from every question manually.

Comment: @OrangeDog - Having to remove it from each individual quesetion is desirable, I think, because it (hopefully) requires you to make sure that it's actually a good idea that you're removing the tag.