# Tags can be locked to prevent their usage. Should we lock the DO NOT USE tags which are too large for current burnination efforts?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-system

There are many tags which would probably be burninated [if doing so was feasible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330494/do-not-use-tags-why-dont-we-remove-them).

> Most of the **DO NOT USE** tags have a lot of questions in them. Those tags used to be valid in the past; we didn't have a quality system (a.k.a. [burninate requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request)) back then. If we tried to remove those tags now, we'd get too many worthless old questions bumped to the front page.

Some tags, especially old ones, appear to simply have too many questions for burnination to be easy, at least not without a significant increase in helpers. Examples: [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events) (15k questions), [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) (68k questions), [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) (37k questions). There are many, many more such tags - just search for [**DO NOT USE**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).

Perhaps these tags will eventually be burninated, like what [happened with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299728/are-we-still-trying-to-axe-the-table) [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table), which had a **DO NOT USE** label at the end of 2014, but still got added to [~2000](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280215/locking-bad-tags#answer-280216) more questions before burnination started 6 months later, because users did not read the tag description before adding it. Those added tags generally did not add any value (or added negative value) to their questions, and resulted in more cleanup work in the long run. (Burnination finished [in February](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/299728/revisions) of this year)

Consider [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web), which officially acquired **DO NOT USE** [in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7175469/revisions) by Shog9, but has gotten multiple *tens of thousands* of questions since then, which may eventually have to be cleaned up.

---

The site does have [the ability to prevent specific tags from being used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151920/add-the-ability-to-lock-tags#answer-268622) in the future, without requiring them to be removed from current questions first. Might we use this ability to prevent these sorts of **DO NOT USE** tags from actually being used, to improve tagging accuracy and question quality, and to reduce future cleanup workload?

Caveats:

- Locked tags are (I think) [expensive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372121/should-burninated-tags-be-blacklisted-by-default#answer-372143). Tags which have already been burninated usually do not need this:

  > every tag [increases processing time] for little gain because most tags don't experience this problem

  But there *would* be much gain for active tags which should not be used, but are still being used daily. (Worst-case, to avoid increasing processing time, remove locked tags which are rarely triggered.)
- Just because a tag has **DO NOT USE** does not mean that it *will definitely* be eventually burninated. Still, if there is a consensus, actually preventing it from being used would be useful.
- [New edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151920/add-the-ability-to-lock-tags#answer-268622) to old posts with a blocked tag *must* remove said tag for the edit to go through. It would probably be helpful for each blocked tag to have its [short message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zM61.png) suggest what an editor should do with it, maybe with a link to a meta post on it.

Note that I am [not asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280215/locking-bad-tags) a "Do we have the ability to..." feature request - we *do* have the ability. I am suggesting that we *use* our ability (or, more precisely, that we make posts to discuss tags, come to a consensus on a lock message, and that the developers use the ability). Figuring out lock messages *now* is far easier and more efficient than having to sort through tens of thousands of questions years later.

Comment: More general: *..users did not read the tag description before adding it...* needs fixing. That is an UX challenge.

Comment: I could also argue that the *Do Not Use* phrase is added prematurely. As a community we seem to prefer to discuss the removal of tags first, which led to the [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/578411), and there the tag excerpt is updated (in step 4) after consensus is reached.

Comment: There are approx. [60 tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1059627) (a few false positives) that have *DO NOT USE* in some form. Roughly half of them are backed by a burninate request.

Comment: There has been discussion [on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250190/burninate-the-web-tag) [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255437/is-there-an-api-to-help-burninate-this-tag), but yes, the phrase should probably only be used as part of a more official process. Pretty sure many of these tags still exist not because of a lack of consensus and discussion, but because of a [lack of manpower](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356820/why-do-some-burninate-request-with-over-20-votes-not-get-featured) - getting to that step 4 takes *so* long.

Comment: Well, we have made [some progress](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46357913#46357913) the last year. When it comes to manpower there are more users prepared to back that statement then to actually get their hands dirty and dig in.

Comment: "Locked tags are (I think) expensive" - to me this just highlights the need to improve how it's implemented. There's really no reason this should be at all expensive, even with much, much more tags than what we have now.

Comment: @rene: For some reason I wanna try automation-aided burnination. I can come up with a lot of high specificity mass queries on most large tags that would really reduce the workload if ran before or during user-level cleanups.

Comment: @Joshua if you don't mind, hop in [Trogdor](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597/trogdor) where you can find what we already have in place and find both regulars and mods involved in these efforts. Ideas to support the effort are appreciated.

Comment: @Dukeling tags on the posts row in the database are character separated, the last time I checked them in the SEDE

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure what you're trying to say. It seems pretty easy to quickly check for blacklisted tags from that representation.

Comment: Another argument I might've seen (which I'm not sure I agree with) against blacklisting tags that still exist is it's confusing. I believe you'll have to remove the tag when making any other edits to a question (although I wouldn't call this a bad thing, and it's not strictly necessary for the system to work like this) and you'll see the tag appearing on questions while being unable to use it yourself (also not really a huge problem).

Comment: @JarrodRoberson See the last paragraph in my question - that question is a feature-request for the ability to lock tags. We now have that feature. My question is suggesting that we discuss *using* that available feature.

Comment: We also have `javascript-objects` - this can be covered by tagging both `javascript` and `object`.

Comment: @JackBashford I'm not sure. "object" is too general and I find `javascript-objects` to be rather descriptive when it comes to what a person is dealing with. A lot of people mistakenly tag their question with `json` when they *don't* have JSON and instead mean objects. And in particular, object literals, as opposed to making an instance of a class.

Comment: @rene the "people don't read tags" needs to be addressed somehow. Some tags have "DO NOT USE" written in capitals and still get used but my bigger gripe is with tags that explicitly say "DO NOT USE if you mean Y". The `java` and `javascript` tags are very often used interchangeably when people mean one or the other. I agree that to a newcomer, they sound very similar, but the site should try to suggest that they aren't. I'm sure other tags have similar problems. The system might try to verify that the user really wants "DO NOT USE" (in some form) tags. Dunno how best to have it not be annoying

Comment: @JackBashford like [tag:excel] and [tag:vba]? That one went [smoothly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace) ....

Comment: [captain-falcon-yes.jpg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQf_JLBh0Zc)

Comment: I filter on the [api] tag in the lose vote queue and can attest to the fact that it routinely gets multiple off-topic questions per day.

Comment: As there is no requirement for consensus before adding "DO NOT USE" to a tag, and the fact that false positives would be abundant, I think this would be a very bad idea. Anyone with enough rep to singlehandedly edit tag wiki excerpts could then lock any tag with just an edit.

Comment: @TinyGiant This isn't a request for an automated system prompted by a normal user edit. This is a request to examine tags currently describe as "DO NOT USE", write lock messages for them as appropriate, and then apply those lock messages.

Comment: Please, stop these tags from being further abused.

Comment: @TinyGiant See the second bullet point: *Still, **if there is a consensus,** actually preventing it from being used would be useful.* Discussion and general community agreement would most certainly be required for every tag beforehand.

Comment: So realistically the question here then is "Can we add locking of the tag to the standard burnination procedure?" in which case I asked for this multiple times and have been repeatedly told that locking of tags is only used if the tag comes back after being burninated.

Answer (score 34):

For the expensive part, can't we just have a client side blocking mechanism instead, it would prevent a lot of clutter happening front end. And people would really have to go out of their way to add it.

On this moment in tageditornew.js there is this event listener on tag-suggestions.

```
Q.on({
        "keydown": D,
        "keyup": N,
        "click": function(e) {
            $(e.target).is("a") || M($(this))
        },
        "focus": function() {
            xt && 1 === a ? M($(this)) : vt = !0
        },
        "blur": function() {
            vt = !1
        }
    }, "div")
```

Which calls

```
function M(e) {
    ut.val(e.data("tag-name")),
    L(),
    v(""),
    m()
}
```

If you'd implement a simple check before this run:

```
function M(e) {
    if(e.text().indexOf('DO NOT USE THIS TAG') > -1) { 
        e.css({
            'background-color':'red',
            'color':'#eeeeee'
        });
        return false;
    }

    ut.val(e.data("tag-name")),
    L(),
    v(""),
    m()
}
```

from the source at https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/tageditornew.js

```
/**
 * Called when a tag suggestion is picked from the autocomplete box - means we have a valid tag from server!
 */
function choose(jTag) {
    if(jTag.text().indexOf('DO NOT USE THIS TAG') > -1) { 
        jTag.css({
            'background-color':'red',
            'color':'#eeeeee'
        });
        return false;
    }
    input.val(jTag.data("tag-name"));
    cancelAutoCompletion();
    editTag("");
    cleanUp();
}
```

It would prevent the tag from being added.
I tested this by putting a break point on the tageditornew.js line, reloading, modifying the script, and it prevented the tag from being added to the bar.

I don't have full insight in the framework, but with a simple warning like this, a visual cue, they will see the do not use(hopefully) and not use it.

Of course this code isn't perfect, it's more a concept, but it puts the action where it should be, at the user, notifying him/her/etc.. that there's something that needs attention.

[image: blocked tag addition]

Comment: We can't really just check for the "DO NOT USE" text, as this can be freely added or removed by any user with enough rep.

Comment: @Dukeling True, but, tag wikis are usually meticulously checked, and one that adds a do not use without a proper meta discussion, will probably fail audits/quickly reverse. This trick/invalid do not use comment would cause a very quick discussion on meta and reversal of the wiki edit.

Comment: What about for API posts? A client-side addition is OK, but something server-side would still have to change to prevent the post from going through.

Comment: @connectyourcharger Well, you catch a bit, so the growth of the "forbidden tags" are stemmed. And I don't know about what all implements the API, I would suspect the mobile app. I don't know how many questions are posted via api. But it will probaly be a lot less than those via the website

Comment: Tip: You can read the unminified source code on [dev.stackoverflow.com](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/tageditornew.js). (see line 1047, `suggestions.on({
            keydown: choice_keydown,
            keyup: choice_keyup, ...`)

Comment: @Tschallacka I'm suspecting some sort of rebel would come and make posts with the API - there are thousands of developers online, and a lot of them are tech-savvy.It's not too far-fetched to think someone from a *community of developers* would try and abuse the system (even if they're not trying to be *bad*, per se).

Comment: @connectyourcharger that would be cool. "hi, i hacked the stack with oauth to post my question about javascript-events. I cannot catch my event. Plz help. Thanks"

Comment: It's an interesting idea that could block most future bad-tag attempts, but the system *already* has the code needed to *fully* block said tags, and in a foolproof way, on the backend. The only roadblocks are moderator approval, and community consensus for each tag.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'll look and update the code tomorrow, I'm on mobile now. Thank you for pointing that out.  What this would allow is to stem the influx of new questions, which would help a gradual burniation of the tags that go in the thousands. Without new posts popping up as much it won't be a sisyphean task anymore. Plus it aids people in reading what's wrong with the tag(hopefully)

Comment: @Tschallacka There's a possibility that somebody's going to do it, and it would be unreasonable to think otherwise. We as a community should be thinking with 100% confidence, not 90%.

Comment: If you can block (or advise against) 90% of invalid uses of the tags, it's better than nothing. Also, if it's about making clear that the tags should not be used (assuming people overlook that fact), there is probably a only very small number of users that would use the API or any other work-around to use those tags. Of course, server side check is better if you want to completely close the gap, but this client-side solution could be a quick win.

Comment: @Tschallacka This would infuriate MySQL users: *"DO NOT USE this tag for other DBs such as SQL Server, SQLite etc."*

Comment: @JL2210 we could do without them ;)

Comment: @JL2210 what if I modify the string to `DO NOT USE THIS TAG`.

Comment: @Tschallacka Then less cases of this would be caught. We really need to find a list of "DO NOT USE" tags and have each one reviewed and banned if needed.

Comment: @JL2210 Ideally there would be "blocked" marker instead of banned, as an intermediate status, that would add a css class that the front end JS could catch and filter, because a list would need updating/polling which adds extra serverside overhead. We need a lightweight solution to "stem" the flow of new posts with the DO NOT USE tags.

Comment: @connectyourcharger I see your point, but my counter argument is that what harm does it do if a small number of users try to circumvent this? They post a question with a bad tag? Good job to them I guess? This will still drastically reduce the number of questions using this tag.

Comment: `Do not use this tag if it is a Tuesday, otherwise it is fine`, I think it would be a bad idea to do that.

Comment: @DavidG Let's create a `last-edited-on-not-tuesday` tag! (kidding of course)

Comment: Or a [do-not-use-this-tag-today] tag.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a huge fan of these "DO NOT USE" edits. Primarily because they don't work all that well (as you observed...) but also because they suffer from much the same problem that burninations have: it's easy to convince a few people that a tag isn't useful - you just gotta find people who don't have any interest in it.

We have [a process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) for burnination. We could add a process for locking too - but we need to exercise a bit of caution there: locking a tag should usually be a temporary step on the way to complete removal; with a *very* few exceptions, it should not be a permanent state.

BTW: I didn't add "DO NOT USE" to the [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) tag - I removed it. Then a few years later someone added it back. The crux of the argument against [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) was that it's full of bad questions - but removing the tag doesn't remove those questions, nor does putting "DO NOT USE" in its description. At best, it warns a tiny handful of people away from using it on otherwise-reasonable questions; at worst, it deprives answerers of yet another bit of signal they could otherwise use to ignore bad questions.

Comment: While it would obviously be better to always be able to properly clean up any tag deemed to not be a useful tag, the reality of the situation is most tags that there just isn't the manpower to manually clean up all of the tags that don't belong.  Not locking tags that are unambiguously unhelpful just because there isn't enough manpower to clean it up entirely doesn't solve the problem.  Just because it can't be solved perfectly doesn't mean locking the tag doesn't still provide *some* benefit.  Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good and all that.

Comment: The bit I'm missing here is what benefit - even minimal benefit - is being provided, @Servy. The critical guidance is what comes *after* "DO NOT USE": the list of more appropriate tags. In a certain sense what we really need here isn't so much a lock but something akin to a multi-target synonym that prompts the author to disambiguate. As an imperfect solution, I'd like to see less BIG CAP STATEMENTS and more getting to the point.

Comment: The benefit is that by being unable to use the tag they thought they should used they're forced to figure out what they need to use instead, and there's a good chance they end up reading the information presented about the tags they ought to be using in their attempt to resolve their problem, rather than never reading the tag description in the first place because they never realized there was a problem.

Comment: That's a good groundrule for a process then, @servy: define a fixed set of alternative tags.

Comment: Agreed.  It's mostly of value for ambiguous tags, not superfluous tags.