# Feature Request: Allow tags to be protected in cases of dispute/cleanup/burnination so only members with enough reputation can use them

Tags: feature-request, tags

### Background

Recently I've been looking at the burnination process and have even requested a burnination myself. But in going through this for the first time, I see some glaring inefficiencies not only with the burnination process (which this post is not about), but with what happens with poorly-defined tags that do not meet burnination criteria.

For instance, [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) did not meet today's burnination criteria when it was requested for burnination 7 years ago. However, the tag except has stated since 2013:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It is ambiguous and not helpful.

and the tag description explains further about how to properly tag questions that may have to do with an option (which is never to use that tag). Yet, **since these updates** to the tag **saying not to use it** there have been **over 1K questions asked which have had this tag assigned**. This is effectively a signpost that not everybody reads and it continues to add ambiguity to the site. There are many other examples of this and even examples of previously burninated tags that come back from the dead, or tags with ignored signposts about their usage. In some cases tag cleanup is prolonged simply because the volume of new uses of those tags exceeds the rate at which they are cleaned up.

Keep in mind that this request does not center around giving trusted community members the ability to blacklist or burninate tags via way of specialized tools and automation. While tedious, the burnination/rename/disambiguate process is this way on purpose and I don't disagree with it. Rather, this request centers around functionality to help not only with burnination, but signpost tags or other tags that are poorly defined and we do not want such tags to be used while they are cleaned up in one form or another.

---

### Proposal

[It is a known issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work) that there are very few tools for the community to manage poorly defined tags, and as stated above tags can often come back from the dead or guidelines about their usage are ignored. As it stands, it seems only SE devs and possibly Community Managers can blacklist tags from use. This is probably a safe decision, but I think we can do a bit better here where the community can be involved in how disputed tags are used. A similar problem has been solved in another space on this site. For questions with high traffic that attract low quality answers, that question may be protected so only privileged users with high enough reputation may answer or interact with the post.

**I propose that tags should also be able to be protected in this way by members of the community with sufficiently high enough reputation.** A protected tag would not be able to be used except by existing badge holders of that tag, or users with sufficiently high-enough reputation.

Arguably, the amount of rep for protecting tags should meet or exceed the amount of reputation required for protecting questions (15000 rep), perhaps even added to the 20000 rep mark of a **Trusted User**. Community-elected moderators would also be able to perform this as part of their moderation duties, especially as mods are often involved in tag disputes and cleanup. Alternatively, grant this permission only to community-elected moderators and the Community Manager. That would be sufficient and a welcome step forward in improving the tag dispute, cleanup, and burnination process.

**To use a protected tag, I propose you would at least need the 1500 reputation required for creating tags.** Perhaps existing holders of that tag's silver or gold badge could be allowed to use it as well. Either criteria should imply the end user understands the site and its functions, including how tags work.

Comment: I agree, but would go a bit further by locking them so that no one can use them unless there's a Meta consensus that they're OK to use. This approach also requires no extra coding on the SE devs' part. Pretty similar discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385685

Comment: The only reason I didn't propose that is because while it helps the DO NOT USE case and proper burnination, it might hinder disambiguation efforts or other efforts around a disputed tag. So I proposed a middle ground that, not unlike protected questions, sufficient reputation would allow one to use a protected tag. It does not have to be 1500, I suggested it be *at least* 1500.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding your first proposal, one unhappy person with a decent amount of rep can prevent millions of people from using tags such as [java]? Or, if you're limiting it to moderators, why not allow them to actually add a tag to the blocklist? What's so special about 1500+ rep users that they should be allowed to use tags like that?

Comment: @Laurel I would counter with asking what is so special about 1500+ rep users that they get to create potentially off-topic, ambiguous, or dangerous tags? Previous requests for mods to add tags to the blacklist have either been rejected or ignored (which to be fair this request could be rejected or ignored as well), I feel this is a happy medium if SE has some actual reason not to grant mods access to the blacklist. We already allow gold tag badge holders to unilaterally close questions as dupes which has sometimes been used maliciously in the past, but it is not a common occurrence.

Comment: Additionally, if someone does abuse their privileges, especially with a tag like `java` it'll get noticed and reversed pretty quick and said user will very likely have some consequences levied. You can go down this rabbit hole far enough and say no user with any amount of rep should be trusted to do any moderation work, because a minority of them could potentially abuse their privileges.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Mods can't add/remove/change entries to/from/in the blocklist. I'm not aware of mods *ever* being able to do so. Only SE staff can make changes to the blocklist. There are explicit criteria for tags to be even considered for addition to the blocklist. Those criteria are 1) that the tag was previously burninated, and 2) the tag was recreated after the burnination was complete.

Comment: @Makyen That's the point, mods don't have the ability to do this today. I was addressing Laurel as to why I didn't propose mods get access to the tag blacklist. That's still some good info though I didn't know about criteria for being added to the blacklist. Re-reading that comment, I worded that poorly; I meant that previous feature requests for mods to ***be able to*** add tags to the blacklist have either been rejected or ignored.

Comment: @CertainPerformance that would be the same as blacklisting the tag, something that devs have said on repeated occasions to be very expensive and should be done sparingly. Better yet would be to remove it and keep a list outband of the postid in case we want to readd them later on.

Comment: @Braiam Agreed, and what I've proposed would be reversible for tags which are not egregiously recreated or which benefit from temporary protection (which should be sent to the proper blacklist in that case)